# jQuery animated dataview sorter

Tags: jquery, extjs4, tablesorter, dataview, animated

Does anyone know a dataview sorter in jQuery similar to this one (built with extjs) http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/view/animated-dataview.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) plugin.